# Display flex property not working properly in RTL

Tags: css, flexbox

I have used flex property in LTR it's working fine and displayed as 3 columns, but I have use the same code for RTL it's displaying in 2 columns.

**CSS**

```
.adv{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100vw;
}
```

**Screenshot (Right to Left)**

[image]

**Screenshot (Left to Right)**

[image]

Comment: What do you mean LTR and RTL?

Comment: Left to Right language and Right to Left language..I am not sure weather its the reason for the issue but it occurs whenever i switch languages..

Comment: That maybe the case. Could you make a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/) or [weave](http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor)?